# When and where are controller's properties supposed to be set?

Tags: iphone, properties, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

This time, I was wondering when I was supposed to set my properties ...

I got a nav bar which I use to push a new controller (controlling a Web View) :

```
NewsViewController *webViewController = [[NewsViewController alloc] init]; // I create my controller

webViewController.urlText = @"http://www.google.fr"; // I set the property

InfonulAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

[delegate.newsNavController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

[webViewController release];
```

I don't know why but the code below doesn't work :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { //viewDidLoad from my webViewController

   [super viewDidLoad];

   //Create a URL object.
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlText];
   //URL Requst Object
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   //Load the request in the UIWebView.
   [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

I just want to create a UIWebView but I need to give the controller the URL to use !

Any idea where and when my urlText property needs to be set ?!?

Cheers,

Gauthier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use property correctly? Like

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *urlText;
```

If so, try to use a customized init method like this;

```
-(id)initWithUrl:(NSString *)url
{
     if(self = [super init])
     {
          self.urlText = url;

     }
     return self;
}
```

dont forget to release urlText in dealloc. Now use;

```
NewsViewController *webViewController = [[NewsViewController alloc] initWithUrl:@"someUrl"];
```